# Converter uma string com Código HTML em um objeto(Tag) HTML

Tags: javascript, html, android, mobile, script

bom dia. Estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou realizando a integração entre o aplicativo mobile da empresa e a plataforma do VIMEO. Estou usando a integração do tipo oEmbed, e Pela documentação deles (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed#examples), quando faço a solicitação é retornado um XML em que um dos elementos() vem com o a tag  já pronta para integrar no site. Essa parte de recuperar a informação e passar para o javscript do aplicativo já está normal, consegui fazer ela corretamente.

O problema ocorre quando eu passo a Tag para a pagina html. Ela não interpreta como um elemento comum do html, e sim como um texto. Dessa forma, o vídeo não carrega na página.

Gostaria de saber de que forma posso realizar essa conversão de texto para um tipo que seja interpretado como uma tag HTML, de forma que funcione o vídeo de forma correta.

Abaixo, segue um trecho de código de uma tentativa que fiz no arquivo javascript de realizar a conversão do texto para elemento HTML, seguindo alguns exemplos que vi quando pesquisei.

```
modulos : function(idCurso, idMatricula){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var parser = new DOMParser();//<<<CRIA O ELEMENTO DOM
    fn.load('conteudo.html');

    $.ajax({
        url: window.api_url + '/curso/getModulosCurso',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {idCurso : idCurso}
    }).done(function(response){

        $.each(response, function(i,elem){
            $('#select-carousel').append($('<option>', {
                value: elem.IdModulo,
                text: elem.Titulo,
            }));                
            elem.HtmlVimeo = $.parseHTML(elem.HtmlVimeo, "text/html");//<<<CONVERTE A STRING RECEBIDA EM HTML
        });
```

Nesse próximo trecho, como o código é puxado na página principal.

```
                    {{if TipoConteudo == 'Vídeo MPEG'}}
                        {{:HtmlVimeo}}  <!-- PUXA A VARIÁVEL HtmlVimeo, QUE CONTÉM A TAG HTML
                    {{/if}}
```

A seguir, imagem da forma como a página HTML está interpretando o código acima:

[image: Imagem da interpretação do HTML]

OBS: Para me certificar de que esse trecho da variável HtmlVimneo(`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/116061334?app_id=XXXXX" width="480" height="272" frameborder="0" title="Power Point - Aula 1" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`) está correto, eu copiei e colei ele no local do segundo código, para ver se o vídeo funcionaria. O Funcionamento foi normal, demonstrando que o erro está mesmo nessa interpretação da variável como texto e não como HTML.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Mesmo usando o parseHTML está indo como string?

Comment: Cara, olha essa resposta -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103962/converting-html-string-into-dom-elements Pode ajudar

Comment: @dvd Sim, mesmo utilizando o parseHtml está indo como string.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Já tinha visto essa resposta, até fui por algumas delas para tentar solucionar, mas mesmo assim não resolveu.